# Show the number of files in an hg repo?

Tags: mercurial

I have a very large and growing repo.  Is there any handy way to have mercurial show the number of files tracked in a repo?  I don't want to list the files, I just want the file count.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hg manifest` will print a list of version controlled files for the current revision, one file per line -- so on unix, `hg manifest | wc -l` would work. (Alternatively, `hg status --all` prints a list of all files, including ignored files, so you can count those lines if you want to include those too.)

Comment: Thank you.  Worked perfectly and was quite fast compared to most operations on my repo.